# remove wp admin menu by customer user role

Tags: user-access, user-roles

I have a custom user that i'm trying to minimize access for. I have a few admin menus in the toolbar that I'd like removed but only for this customer user role. I currently have it working for everyone that isn't an admin but I can't get the if function correct by user role. My current code:

```
//Remove admin menu items if not admin
function remove_admin_bar_links() {
    global $wp_admin_bar, $current_user;

    if ($current_user->ID != 1) {
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('updates');          // Remove the updates link
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');         // Remove the comments link
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-content');      // Remove the content link
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');          // Remove the WP Logo link
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wpseo-menu');       // Remove the Yoast SEO menu
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_links' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [wp_get_current_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) function to get current logged in user's role

//Remove admin menu items if not admin

```
function remove_admin_bar_links() {
    global $wp_admin_bar, $current_user;

     $user = wp_get_current_user();
     if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
         $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('updates');          // Remove the updates link
         $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');         // Remove the comments link
         $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-content');      // Remove the content link
         $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');          // Remove the WP Logo link
         $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wpseo-menu');       // Remove the Yoast SEO menu
     }
 }
 add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_links' );
```